# Best sort algorithm that can be used for sorting linked list using structures in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Best sort algorithm that can used for sorting linked list using structures in c, which has the least possibility for getting errors (segmentation for example)?

Comment: Any *properly implemented* sorting algorithm will, by definition, work without bugs like that. If you're looking for a sorting algorithm that is impossible to implement improperly, there is no such thing.

Comment: Quoute: "...  has the least possibility for getting **pointer related errors**" Well, that would be an algorithm that do **not** change the pointers but swapped the pointed-to values. However, that would (in most cases) be a rather strange thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do that and to avoid errors would be that you create a new list and then iterate trough the original and in every iteration find the smallest/biggest element and append it to the start/end of the new list, and then delete it from the original list. This has time complexity of O(n^2) so if you want something faster you should look into merge sort which is (in my opinion) the best sorting algorithm for linked lists.